# Javascript Variable scopes (how to access global variable inside a anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var pos=new google.maps.LatLng(60,100);
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                position.coords.longitude);                                            
    map.setCenter(pos);     
});
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+="Before"+pyrmont; 
pyrmont = pos;
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+="After"+pyrmont;
```

So the result i get is that the variable pos value is not obtained from the function. It seems that the function has its own copy of inside the function and not accessible outside. I did google for this problem and tried as suggested in many posts but in vain.

```
var pos=new google.maps.LatLng(60,100);
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position,pos){
        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                     position.coords.longitude);                                               
        map.setCenter(pos);     
  })(pos);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+="Before"+pyrmont; 
  pyrmont = pos;
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML+="After"+pyrmont;
```

Comment: Without knowing the details, I would guess that navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is an asynchronous operation that calls the callback method at a later time. Thus your function has not actually been called yet when you execute the last three lines in the example.

Comment: johusman is spot on. This has nothing to do with variable scope (which works as expected) but with asynchronous programming.

Comment: Okay, thanks, i will rewrite/edit the question with full code for how to get the location and use it with places library of google. Thanks a lot for support